# Python Folium Search feature: how to search by FeatureGroup?

Tags: python, folium

I know it's possible to use the search feature on GeoJson, TopoJson, FeatureGroup, MarkerCluster class objects. I am able to make it work for GeoJson. However I can't make it work for a FeatureGroup. My FeatureGroup contains markers and I want to use the search feature to find markers based on the popup values ideally. Here is a link to a very similar issue (not posted by me, but answering it will help with my issue...). Thanks in advance for any help!
[Folium Search Plugin No Results for FeatureGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57468332/folium-search-plugin-no-results-for-featuregroup/59567613#59567613)

Comment: Please can you give some example code/what you've tried so far?